# Selecting date range withinthe next 14 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, select

I am using the following mySQL query to select entries where date_start is within the next 14 days, for the most part it works fine but it is not including entries that are "today"

```
SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( date_start,  ' %d.%m.%Y' ) AS date_formatted
FROM calendar_event
WHERE Date_start
BETWEEN NOW( ) 
AND DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 14 
DAY ) 
AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3 < amount
AND amountpaid > 0
```

any ideas how i can make it also show entries that are scheduled with todays date

many thanks

Comment: now() is creating the current time so e.g. 2012-11-17 19:58:00, but what you want is 2012-11-17 00:00:00, so use date(now())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( date_start,  ' %d.%m.%Y' ) AS date_formatted
FROM calendar_event
WHERE Date_start
BETWEEN CURDATE() 
AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 14 DAY ) 
AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3 < amount
AND amountpaid > 0
```

At any time in the day except 12:00am, the value returned by `NOW()` will be greater than 12:00am of the morning of that day.

Answer (score 1):

You try this

```
SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( date_start, ' %d.%m.%Y' ) AS date_formatted FROM calendar_event WHERE Date_start BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATE_ADD(GETDATE()+14) AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3 < amount AND amountpaid > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) so you can compare only by date and not by hours and minutes, which is the wrong case here because it compares to the current time that is some hours ahead from 00:00

Comment: Assuming your DB rows dates are like Y-m-d 00:00:00